# getRequestDispatcher returning null even though path/file exists in webapp

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7, servlet-filters

I am trying to get a login page from within a Filter, like so:
context.getRequestDispatcher("/loginpage.jsp")
(Which I then want to forward to)

Now, if i do context.getContext("/loginpage.jsp"), it properly shows me the filesystem path to the resource I want. So that means it can indeed see it. However using request dispatcher it just wont resolve.

I am running this tomcat in a very non standard way. I am calling java.exe with all the properties and options that catalina.sh normally would call. I would agree that this could be the cause of all my problems, but I am still interested in finding out what could be breaking in here.

(Note: This runs like this only in dev environments and has been working properly without complains till recently. However I recently made major changes to the dev env, which apparently broke something)

**EDIT:**
Another point I just noticed was, that even trying to access completely static resources (like /css/styles.css, etc) was failing. So it isnt a specific problem with getrequestDispatcher, but something more fundamental I presume?

Comment: in your exploded war where is this login.jsp related to your web root

Comment: It is right under the root of the war file. So when exploded it goes to tomcat/webapps/<mywar>/loginpage.jsp  (Which i verified actually happens)

Comment: Bit of a guess but it might work if you put it in `/WEB-INF/loginpage.jsp`?

Comment: I'm not really sure that will help tbh. jsp's dont really belong in WEB-INF... infact tomcat will not even allow files in WEB-INF to be served up via the http.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was really simple and down to a misunderstanding of how the CATALINA_HOME / CATALINA_BASE works:
Anything placed in CATALINA_HOME/conf seems to be ignored. So even though I had web.xml and content.xml in the CATALINA_HOME/conf it ignored that.

There are no exceptions or errors in any of the logs (application logs, catalina.logs, localhost.log, host-managed.log, etc). So it is really hard to debug this problem.

This question helped me figure the answer  out:
https://serverfault.com/questions/205154/war-deployed-in-tomcat-not-showing-up-at-url-getting-404-instead